# LMS template: to delete header and footer

Tags: overleaf, templates, journal, documentclass

I'm using Overlead's template of London Mathematical Society lms class [lms.cls], but I got this on top right of the first page

[image]

How can I remove this one and this following one on the bottom left as a footnote (also in the first page)?

[image]

I can't find where to modify these (normally I double click on the right panel, which is a preview containing equations, texts, etc., of Overleaf and then it will bring me to the place of the code in accordance with the equation). But for these two, It places me to the place that is not related to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add after `\documentclass{lms}`

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\@journal{}
\def\@footnotetwo{}
\makeatother
```